# Combining two functions for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to combine these two functions in my functions.php file. I have tried a couple variations but cant seem to fine the right one. It works as it is broken into two functions but now my curiosity has got the best of me.

Im removing fields in my checkout page in Woo Commerce, two fields. I cant figure out to to call them both in one function so I just used two to make it work but would just like to know how to make it into one.

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields_1( $fields ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'dealer_group' ) && isset( $fields['billing']['rep_name'] ) ) {
        unset( $fields['billing']['rep_name'] );
    }

     return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields_1' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields_2( $fields ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'dealer_group' ) && isset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] ) ) {
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
    }

     return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields_2' );
```

Comment: Why can't you just put the two `if` statements in one function?

Comment: Just add the second `if` statement into the first function.

Answer (score 4):

You just refactor those two functions into one.
No need to check for `isset` as unset will not do anything if it isn't set.

```
function custom_override_fields($fields) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'dealer_group' ) ) {
          unset( $fields['billing']['rep_name'] );
          unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
    }   

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: This is a properly researched answer with regards to `isset` and `unset`.

Comment: This was along the lines of what I was thinking but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_override_fields($fields) {
   if ( ! current_user_can( 'dealer_group' ) && isset( $fields['billing']['rep_name'] ) ) {
      unset( $fields['billing']['rep_name'] );
   }
   if ( ! current_user_can( 'dealer_group' ) && isset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] ) ) {
      unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
   }
   return $fields;
}
```

Just combined the two ifs.

Comment: This does not work either. Both fields stay visible for both users types

Comment: @DanCrowe Then the problem don't come from this code :/ Its an another part of the code that causes this bug.